# How to transform Dataframe Mapper to PMML?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, pmml, sklearn2pmml

I want to use multiple PMMLs to keep the transformation of the data and the application of the model separate. Here is the code I am using. I am doing this because I want to include some kind of winsorizing on my data.

```
train_stats = {}
continous_domains = []
for cont in con_vars: 
    # REMOVE -1 values to not distort the quantiles
    cont_val = np.asarray(train_data_sub[train_data_sub[cont] != -1][cont])
    _95 = np.percentile(cont_val[~np.isnan(cont_val)], 95)
    _05 = np.percentile(cont_val[~np.isnan(cont_val)], 5)
    _50 = np.percentile(cont_val[~np.isnan(cont_val)], 50)
    train_stats[cont] = [_05, _50, _95]
    continous_domains.append(
        ([cont], [
            ContinuousDomain(
                missing_values = [-1], 
                missing_value_treatment="as_value", 
                missing_value_replacement= _50,
                outlier_treatment ='as_extreme_values', 
                low_value = _05, 
                high_value = _95, 
                dtype = float
                )
            ]))

data_mapper = DataFrameMapper(continous_domains, df_out=True)
data_mapper.fit(train_data_sub)

data_mapper.transform(train_data_sub)
pmml_pipeline = PMMLPipeline(steps = [
    ('DataframeMapper', data_mapper)])
path_name = f"Trafo_{str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H-%M'))}.pmml"
sklearn2pmml(pmml_pipeline, path_name, debug=True)
```

It kinda works but the returned .pmml file only includes the data dictionary without the specifications of the setted high/low values etc.

Interestingly when I am putting a LogisticRegression inside the Pipeline I get a correct looking PMML but there are only two outputs and I actually want to get all the transformed values from the Dataframe Mapper.

Can anyone help me here? Really struggling to find a solution.

Thank you so much and best regards

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the returned .pmml file does only include the data dictionary without the specifications of the setted high/low values etc.

The domain specification gets stored in two places inside the PMML document.

First, the decision whether some input value is valid or invalid, gets encoded into the `/PMML/DataDictionary/DataField` element. For example, specifying that "Sepal.Length" only accepts values within the `[4.3, 7.9]` range:

```xml
<DataField name="Sepal_Length" displayName="Sepal length in cm" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
  <Interval closure="closedClosed" leftMargin="4.3" rightMargin="7.9"/>
</DataField>
```

Second, the decision how the pre-categorized input value (ie. valid/invalid/missing) should be handled by any given model. This is encoded into the `/PMML/<Model>/MiningSchema/MiningField` elements. For example, specifying that invalid and missing values are not permitted:

```xml
<MiningSchema>
  <MiningField name="Sepal_Length" invalidValueTreatment="returnInvalid" missingValueTreatment="returnInvalid"/>
</MiningSchema>
```

Your pipeline does not contain a model object, so there is physically no place where the second part of the domain specification could be stored.

> Interestingly when I am putting a LogisticRegression inside the Pipeline I get a correct looking PMML but there I only have two outputs...

The SkLearn2PMML package performs PMML optimization, where unused field declarations are automatically removed in order to spare human and computer cognition efforts.

Looks like your `LogisticRegression` model object only uses two input fields then.

You could try replacing `LogisticRegression` with some other model type that uses all input fields. Some "greedy" algorithm such as random forest might be a good fit.

TLDR: You can't separate domain decorators such as `ContinuousDomain` from the actual model object. If you want to use pre-fitted domain decorators in multiple pipelines, then you should store them as pure Python objects in Pickle or Dill data formats. Alternatively, generate some utility function (and package it as a Python library) that you can import and activate conveniently.